# Quick Robots.txt question

Tags: robots.txt

Will the following robots.txt syntax correctly block all pages on the site that end in "_.php"? I don't want to accidentally block other pages.

```
User-Agent: *    
Disallow: /*_.php
```

Also, am I allowed to have both "Allow: /" and "Disallow:" commands in the same robots.txt file? Thanks!

Comment: The first line should begin with "User-agent" and not "User-Agent"; it is very reasonable to expect some/most crawlers to parse your robots.txt file with case-sensitivity, so a "User-Agent" field could be disregarded entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want certain files (but not others) excluded, you must group them into directories, e.g.:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
```

Per [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html), asterisks are not supported in the "Disallow" field:

> Note also that globbing and regular expression are not supported in either the User-agent
>   or Disallow lines. The '*' in the User-agent field is a special value meaning "any robot". Specifically, you cannot have lines like "User-agent: *bot*", "Disallow: /tmp/*" or "Disallow: *.gif".

Additionally, there is no such thing as an "Allow" field.  Everything is allowed by default, and specific items are disallowed by exception.

**References:**

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard
- http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: I'm developing some pages that I don't want crawled yet, and they exist on the server in the form of filename_.php instead of filename.php. How would you propose I block those files from being crawled? A meta tag in each one's <head>?

Comment: Standard practice would be to build separate development and test environments.  In a full-on professional operation, nothing is moved to an internet-facing production server until it is ready for prime time.  Options include installing XAMPP on your development workstation and using it as a development environment (http://localhost), or creating a subdomain on your hosted site (http://test.yourdomain.com/), or perhaps even just uploading a copy of the site to a subfolder (http://www.yourdomain.com/test/).  You can use .htpasswd to enable minimal security for an internet-facing test site.

Comment: Another thought: it's also important to note that robots.txt is a voluntary system to "suggest" that certain pages should not be crawled.  It may stop good crawlers, but it certainly will not stop evil ones.

Comment: Thanks Miles. Yeah, I had heard that robots.txt is not a hard rule, and also know I should have developed in an offline or protected online environment. It was one of those "was just going to be one page but turned into the whole site" redesigns/redevelopments, and it was my fault for not moving it offline. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Miles' answer covers the standards. The most famous crawler, Googlebot, extends the standards and does understand Allow as well as (limited) pattern matching.

I find Google's webmaster tools quite helpful. They have a whole tool devoted to just [helping you build a correct robots.txt](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449). You do need to have the pages (or at least stub test pages) uploaded before you can run a "robots.txt test", though.